# Get last record with column names of all the tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the lastest value of all the tables along with their column names instead of selecting each table. I came across the following select query, but it only returns the column names, if i use * instead of column_name, there is a lot of unnecessary details that i don't need.

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'classicmodels'  
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```

I only need column name with the lastest record in that column.

Comment: *the last value of all the tables* ?? What is it?

Comment: the latest record inserted into a column. Edited the last to latest

Comment: The latest - by timestamp? by autoincrement? By any column with definite name?  Anycase you must use dynamic SQL.

Comment: by timestamp. all the tables have a timestamp column

Comment: Does this "timestamp column" have definite name in all tables? for example, `created_at`.

Comment: yes, the timestamp column name is same in all the tables ex: time_col.

Comment: No problems, use iterative stored procedure with cursor by your query and dynamic SQL.

Comment: can you please share an example.

Comment: An example of what? cursor? iteration over it? dynamic SQL? All these examples can be found in Reference Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to read all the tables latest records using phyton sql connector. There could be better ways of doing this, but because i'm not allowed to work in a running database, I opted this approach.

```
import logging
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3306,
    user="root",
    password="root",
    database="classicmodels")

mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True , dictionary=True)

sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'classicmodels'"
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
tables = [d['TABLE_NAME'] for d in myresult]

for x in tables:
    sql1 = "select * from {}".format(x)
    mycursor.execute(sql1)
    myresult1 = mycursor.fetchone()
    for val, cal in myresult1.items():
        print(f'{val} is {cal}')
```